# Swagger codegen build fails

Tags: api, swagger, code-generation, swagger-codegen, swagger-php

I've asked this [question](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/8989) in the swagger github repository but the community doesn't look very responsive, so I'm going to try here.

Following the [README](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/README.md#getting-started) I'm running this commands to generate a PHP client (but it could be any other language):

```
git clone https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen
cd swagger-codegen
mvn clean package
java -jar modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate 
\
-i http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json \
-l php \
-o /var/tmp/php_api_client
```

and I get the following error:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar
```

Does anybody have the same error? I'm trying to figure out if it's just me. Maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today (1/10/19) it only works with Java version 7 or 8. I had to downgrade from version 10 to make it work.

Comment: This workaround is still working as of today (Apr 9) on Ubuntu 18.